# How to solve dependency problem on installing mysql to ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

How can I solve dependency problems on installing mysql to ubuntu 20.04? I tried

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/
configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned
 error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What solutions have you tried, apart from using `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: Try `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt -f install`. I found this on https://linuxhint.com/prevent_fix_package_dependency_errors_ubuntu/

Comment: Because of `mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet`, you could try `sudo apt reinstall mysql-server`

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get purge 'mysql*'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-8.0
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

But in the future, have care about the package names you add after `sudo apt-get install`

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)